# Android HTML hybrid app best database approach

Tags: android, database, html, android-webview, android-sqlite

I'm developer a relatively simple android app using a hybrid approach of native android controls and a central webview.

The problem I'm having is implementation of a database. Is it better practise to use the deprecated HTML5 database storage method (allowing use of SQL) or is it better practise to use android native databases, and use javascript to push and pull that data into the webview?

Any reading material would be a brilliant bonus. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would be using a webView in the firstplace, if it's a native app and you're thinking about tying it to android specifically on the web side than why not just make it fully and android app?

Comment: There is a relatively new approach which allows for quick development, cross device compatibility and even thing like remote in-app updates all to be done very easily and very quickly. It has draw backs and will never meet that of a native app, but for basic data display like I'm doing it seemed the most apt approach.